# Hooks API - Avoid state overwrite when setting state after await statement

Tags: reactjs, async-await, react-hooks

Let's say we have a tile grid with the follow behavior:

- There's a button for adding a tile. The tile will decide if it should be a red or blue tile after some time thinking (1-3secs). The tile will be green while it's thinking what color it should be.
- Clicking a title will remove the tile from the grid

Let `tiles` be an array of tile colors which will serve as the state of the tile grid and `setTiles` as the setter of that state. Given the grid behavior, `setTiles` should be called during these events:

- on click of a tile. The clicked tile should be removed from `tiles`.
- on click of the add button. A green tile must be added to `tiles`.
- after a tile decides what it's color is. The corresponding green value in `tiles` must be changed to red or green.

I've prepared a [codepen](https://codepen.io/cephtahrioh/pen/KKKVOwZ) of a simple implementation of the grid detailed above. The issue with this is that calls to `setTiles` after an `await` statement overwrites state changes that happened between the start and end of the asynchronous statement. I think this is because the function only has reference to the state value before starting the async operation.

What's the best architecture (component changes, callback passing, tile data structure), **using SFCs and the Hooks API**, to avoid the unintended overwrites and, ultimately, the tile grid having an updated array of tile data at all times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by using `useReducer`. Wasn't aware that with `useReducer`, you have a "synchronised" state for all dispatched actions. The state overwrite wasn't an issue with the seemingly-central state with reducers. Working code [here](https://codepen.io/cephtahrioh/pen/rNNeazP).